# Openfire server not getting started

Tags: java, openfire, xmmp

I am using Windows server 2012R2 and installed openfire 3.10.2. But stop working now. When i am trying start it from window service its show message
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Dpi.jpg)

below are the log..

```
2016.03.10 21:47:56 org.jivesoftware.xmpp.workgroup.search.ChatSearchManager - Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 16,335 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 16,335 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3604)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2838)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxyStatement.invoke(ProxyStatement.java:100)
    at org.logicalcobwebs.proxool.ProxyStatement.intercept(ProxyStatement.java:57)
    at $java.lang.AutoCloseable$$EnhancerByProxool$$f69d47d.executeQuery(<generated>)
    at org.jivesoftware.xmpp.workgroup.search.ChatSearchManager.rebuildIndex(ChatSearchManager.java:721)
    at org.jivesoftware.xmpp.workgroup.search.ChatSearchManager.rebuildIndex(ChatSearchManager.java:454)
    at org.jivesoftware.xmpp.workgroup.search.ChatSearchManager.updateIndex(ChatSearchManager.java:472)
    at org.jivesoftware.xmpp.workgroup.WorkgroupManager$5.run(WorkgroupManager.java:564)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:112)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:159)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3158)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3615)
    ... 22 more
```

And Mysql Connection Details in openfire.xml

```
 <connectionProvider> 
    <className>org.jivesoftware.database.DefaultConnectionProvider</className> 
  </connectionProvider>  
  <database> 
    <defaultProvider> 
      <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>  
      <serverURL>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/openfire?rewriteBatchedStatements=true</serverURL>  
      <username>root</username>  
      <password>root</password>  
      <testSQL>select 1</testSQL>  
      <testBeforeUse>false</testBeforeUse>  
      <testAfterUse>false</testAfterUse>  
      <minConnections>5</minConnections>  
      <maxConnections>100</maxConnections>  
      <connectionTimeout>1.0</connectionTimeout> 
    </defaultProvider> 
  </database>  
  <setup>true</setup>
```

warn log are

```
2016.03.11 00:05:48 org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler - Closing connection due to exception in session: (0x00000002: nio socket, server, /223.184.188.108:45771 => 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5222)
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:273)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:44)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:690)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:664)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:653)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1124)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2016.03.11 00:05:48 org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler - Closing connection due to exception in session: (0x00000003: nio socket, server, null => 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:5222)
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:273)
    at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:44)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:690)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:664)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:653)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$600(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1124)
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception shows that Openfire Server is unable to communicate with the database.
You need to make sure that the database is up and running.

Comment: Have you verified that openfire.xml in conf folder contains correct db connection?

Comment: db connection settings also seem fine. One more thing to troubleshoot is, provide startup logs from info.log, warn.log, error.log when you start openfire. Just to check at which point it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your database is running and TCP port should be enabled

Go to control panel then go to security and check TCP inbound and outbound rule for database if you're using SQL server then port number is 1433 if rule is not define then define rule for it and it'll work fine for you